# Drop Down Box linked to Mysql and Search Function

Tags: php, html, ajax

Good Day

I have the following code, I am trying to link and HTML drop downlist with my MYSQL database to echo all the staff names in the DB. I also want to create a search function not just to show all the staff details but also to filter them as i start typing their names. I have the current scripts but the search function is not working currently.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<?php
    $hostname="****";
    $dbname="covid_19";
    $username="root";
    $password="***";

        $conn=mysqli_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Connection Failed" .mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from staff");
        echo "<select id='search'>";
            echo "<option>-- Search Employee Name -- </option>";
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "<option>$row[ename]</option>";
                }
        echo "</select>";
                echo "<hr/>";
mysqli_close($conn)
    ?>
```

The following line according to what I am trying is to create the search feature but not working.

```
<script>$("#search").chosen();</script>
```

The database connects shows the information as requested just the search function is not working to filter

Answer (score 0):

Pls. try this as you are echoing the html in the same file:

You need to update your code as per below:

```
$html = "<select id='search'>";
$html .= "<option>-- Search Employee Name -- </option>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $html .= "<option>$row[ename]</option>";
}
$html .= "</select>";
$html .= "<hr/>";

echo $html;

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
</script>
```

You can also preview the code [here with example](https://paiza.io/projects/ZMHvZnSOUVutlz_ve--X9g)

Comment: Do I still run it as a script <script>$("#search").trigger("chosen:updated");</script>, tried it this way still just shows dropdown no fileter

Comment: @TrevorAckermann i have updated my answer can you pls. try this.